# Supervised Learning: Cosine Similarity as Loss function?

Tags: machine-learning, supervised-learning

For supervised learning, the loss function should be differentiable so that back-propagation can be performed. I am wondering if it is possible to use loss function that computes the cosine similarity? Is such task more align with reinforcement learning? (In this case, the cosine similarity is used as reward function).